# strtotime afternoon times reflecting 0

Tags: php, strtotime

I've got an issue where strtotime returns my afternoon times as 0.

This is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
$from = strtotime($_GET['meeting_date'] . ' ' . $_GET['meeting_start'] . ':00 ' . date('A',$_GET['meeting_start']));
$to = strtotime($_GET['meeting_date'] . ' ' . $_GET['meeting_end'] . ':00 ' . date('A',$_GET['meeting_end']));
```

Basically, a user selects the date (2012-06-19) and types in a start time (filtered, 14:00) and end time (filtered, 15:00).

This piece then converts the strings given to seconds.

It works with anything I type before 13:00, but returns 0 when I type anything after 12:59

Some test cases:

```
User Input:
  Date: 2012-06-19
  Start: 10:00
  End: 11:50
Result: 
  start: 1340092800
  end: 1340099400

User Input:
  Date: 2012-06-19
  Start: 11:50
  End: 13:00
Result:
  start: 1340099400
  end: 0
```

It's probably a stupid mistake again, but any help would be appreciated. Why does it return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing 12-hour and 24-hour formats together. Date format `'A'` for AM and PM suffixes tells that 12-hour format is in use, so basically you can't deal with hour numbers greater than 12.